# How to parse jSON with anyhashble value?

Tags: json, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

My server supposed to send response like

```
{
title: fcmInboxObject.NotificationTitle,
message : fcmInboxObject.NotificationText,
tile: enums.NotificationCategories.SchoolCalendar,
toId: studentItem._id,
type: fcmInboxObject.NotificationType,
reminder: fcmInboxObject.NotificationReminders
}
```

But I am getting response like

```
[AnyHashable("toId"): 581b7750af32d202243e864b, AnyHashable("type"): Type1, AnyHashable("collapse_key"): do_not_collapse]
remoteMessage [AnyHashable("reminder"): [], AnyHashable("tile"): SchoolCalendar, AnyHashable("from"): 327495396689, AnyHashable("title"): Holiiday Tomorrow, AnyHashable("message"): Holiiday Tomorrow Date: ]
```

I am using FCM for notification and method where I am getting this is

```
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("remoteMessage \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
```

Why this anyhashable is there before keys?
Is there any way to parse this type of JSON or can I get same response as server is sending?

Comment: Perhaps you should check out this solution I found for a similar problem, I hope it helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496320/how-to-parse-this-paypal-json-response-with-anyhashable-value-using-swiftyjson