# How to parse this PayPal JSON response with AnyHashable value using SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json, paypal, hashable

I'm using PaypalSDK to add paypal payment methods to the app I'm developing, it's already working and when the payment is succesful I'm getting a response which I'm converting into a jsonObject but I don't know how to parse it in order to extract just the code from the response. This is the response I'm getting

```
JSON: [AnyHashable("response"): {
code = "******************* -****************-**********************";
}, AnyHashable("response_type"): authorization_code, AnyHashable("client"): {
environment = sandbox;
"paypal_sdk_version" = "2.11.5";
platform = iOS;
"product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
}]
```

And this is what I have on my payPalFuturePaymentViewController method:

```
  func payPalFuturePaymentViewController(_ futurePaymentViewController: PayPalFuturePaymentViewController, didAuthorizeFuturePayment futurePaymentAuthorization: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    print("PayPal Future Payment Authorization Success!")
    self.resultText = futurePaymentAuthorization.description
    let jsonObject = JSON(futurePaymentAuthorization.description)
    print("JSON: \(jsonObject)")
    // send authorization to your server to get refresh token.
    futurePaymentViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

        var paypalPago = PagoItem(noTarjeta: "", fechaExp: "", cvc: "", token: "", tipo: "PayPal")

        self.metodosPago.append(paypalPago)
        self.saveMetodo()

        let destViewController : UIViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pagosLlenos")
        var vcArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers

        vcArray?.removeLast()
        vcArray?.append(destViewController)
        self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(vcArray!, animated: true)
    })
}
```

So what I would like to do is to get the code from the response, put it in a variable and then include that variable in the paypalPago item:

```
 var paypalPago = PagoItem(noTarjeta: "", fechaExp: "", cvc: "", token: PayPalCode, tipo: "PayPal")
```

Any help on how to parse this json and extract the code I need would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

It was very easy actually the problem was that I was storing the string description not the actual JSON response, so I had to change

```
let jsonObject = JSON(futurePaymentAuthorization.description)
```

to

```
let jsonObject = JSON(futurePaymentAuthorization)
```

Now my response looks like this:

```
JSON: {
"client" : {
"environment" : "sandbox",
"product_name" : "PayPal iOS SDK",
"paypal_sdk_version" : "2.11.5",
"platform" : "iOS"
  },
"response_type" : "authorization_code",
"response" : {
"code" : "****************_*********_***********************"
 }
```

And now I can parse it like any normal JSON

```
    let response = jsonObject["response"]["code"].string!
    print(response)

    // send authorization to your server to get refresh token.
    futurePaymentViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        var paypalPago = PagoItem(noTarjeta: "", fechaExp: "", cvc: "", token: response, tipo: "PayPal")
    self.metodosPago.append(paypalPago)
```